# How to customize Silverstripe 3.0 ModelAdmin

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'd like to do a number of small customizations on the ModelAdmin.

1. I'd like to change the text on the 'Add' button to one that is different from the original DataModel.
2. I have a has_many relationship.  I'd like to hide the ability to 'link to existing' so that one cannot search for other 'skills' as per below.

I have the following in the Model:

```
public function getCMSFields() {

    ...

    $characterSkillsField = new GridField(
                'CharacterSkills',
                'Character Skills',
                $this->CharacterSkills(),
                GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
            );

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.CharacterSkills', $characterSkillsField);

    ...

}
```

ANSWER to #2:

// Add the relation editor.

$config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();

// Remove the ability to search and link to other skills.

$config->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter');

$characterSkillsField = new GridField(
            'CharacterSkills',
            'Character Skills',
            $this->CharacterSkills(),
            $config
        );

Answer (score 4):

regarding #1:

add the following to the model class that's managed by the GridField (e.g. 'CharacterSkill') :

```
private static $singular_name = 'foo';
private static $plural_name = 'bar';
```

don't forget flushing the cache afterwards (add '?flush=All' to the url).

the preceding will set the button name to 'Add foo', but it's also possible to set your very own button title, using the following:

```
$config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
$addButton = $config->getComponentByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');
$addButton->setButtonName('my button name');
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Q: is there a good place in the reference docs where these items are elaborated on?

Comment: there's some information on GridField at http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/grid-field, but i couldn't find any info on the add button there; you'll often have to read through the source code to find the nifty details ;)
also, please accept the answer when it works for you, so the issue is marked as resolved - helps all of us: reputation for us, clarity for others :)